# Число правок может уменьшиться?

Tags: дефект, поддержка, правки

На странице участников можно посмотреть [топ по правкам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=all). Ещё недавно у Nicolas Chabanovsky там была 20001 правка.

Сегодня всего 20000.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При каких условиях и в каком случае число правок может уменьшиться?

**UPD:** задал вопрос на MSE: [When edits count could be decreased?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341623/260198)

Comment: удалился исправленный вопрос/ответ?

Comment: @Grundy но это не должно влиять на число правок. Ты же делал правку. Действие завершённое. Факт удаления вопроса не должен на это влиять. По крайней мере, если рассуждать логически)

Comment: ну почему:) репутация же откатывается

Comment: @Grundy не всегда. Вот на MSE недавно удалили вопрос, где у моего ответа было 90 голосов. Репутацию не отняли 

Comment: я про репутацию за правку :)

Comment: @Grundy хм. Надо бы, всё же, на MSE спросить)